# Select particular objects/rows from heatmap in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, r-daisy

I have mixed data type that contain numeric and categorical attributes to which I am planning to apply cluster algorithms.

As a first step, I produced a distance matrix using the daisy() function and Gower distance measure. I have displayed the distance matrix using a heatmap and a levelplot function in R.

It seems as if there is strong similarity between some of the objects in my data and I want to check some of the similar/dissimilar objects to satisfy myself that the measure is working well on my data.

How do I select the similar/dissimilar objects from the heatmap and link them to the original data set to be able to evaluate them?

This is how I plot my heatmap using R. IDX is my distance Matrix.

```
new.palette=colorRampPalette(c("black","yellow","#007FFF","white"),space="rgb") 
    levelplot(IDX_as[1:ncol(IDX_as),ncol(IDX_as):1],col.regions=new.palette(20))

    quartz(width=7,height=6) #make a new quartz window of a given size 
    par(mar=c(2,3,2,1)) #set the margins of the figures to be smaller than default 
    layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=TRUE),widths=c(7,1)) #set the layout of the quartz window. This will create two plotting regions, with width ratio of 7 to 1 
    image(IDX_as[1:ncol(IDX_as),ncol(IDX_as):1],col=new.palette(20),xaxt="n",yaxt="n") #plot a heat map matrix with no tick marks or axis labels 
    axis(1,at=seq(0,1,length=20),labels=rep("",20)) #draw in tick marks 
    axis(2,at=seq(0,1,length=20),labels=rep("",20)) 

    #adding a color legend 
    s=seq(min(IDX_as),max(IDX_as),length=20) #20 values between minimum and maximum values of m 
    l=matrix(s,ncol=length(s),byrow=TRUE) #coerce it into a horizontal matrix 
    image(y=s,z=l,col=new.palette(20),ylim=c(min(IDX),max(IDX)),xaxt="n",las=1) #plot a one-column heat map

    heatmap(IDX_as,symm=TRUE,col=new.palette(20))
```

Comment: You could find the indices where your distance matrix meets a particular threshold, and then use those indices to look at your original data.

Comment: I will try to do this as I am  R beginner, but I appreciate your input a lot

Comment: Try `which(IND > threshold, arr.ind=TRUE)` where `threshold` is some threshold you select.

Comment: Could you post an example please , it will be easier for me to understand. thank you very much for your input.